# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while downloading image f

Tags: swift, fatal-error

Multiple images when downaloded asynchronously and added to array for further shown in different tabs of views

```
var bgImage = UIImage()
        if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: state.bckImageUrl as String) {

            if !state.bgImageDownloaded {

                getDataFromUrl(checkedUrl) { (data, response, error)  in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                        guard let datum = data where error == nil else { return }
                        self.bgView.image = UIImage(data: datum)
                        bgImage = self.bgView.image!    //EXcePtion BAD INSTRUCTION
                        self.bckgrndImages.append(bgImage)
                        state.bgImageDownloaded = true
                    }
                }
            }else{
                self.bgView.image = bckgrndImages[currentStory]
            }
        }
```

Comment: bgImage = self.bgView.image!    //EXcePtion BAD INSTRUCTION Why its crashing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the line of error, print:

```
bgView
bgView.image
```

One of those is nil

If `bgView` is nil, then your outlet from the Main Storyboard connection may be broken. Recobnect it.

If 'bgView.image' is nil, then there is no image in the imageView.